# Trying to install puppet agent in multiple computers using powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

When I run this locally in a server works perfectly:

```
   [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}; $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; $webClient.DownloadFile('https://bod-T2.com:8140/packages/current/install.ps1', 'install.ps1'); .\install.ps1 extension_requests:pp_role=utility extension_requests:pp_environment=e1 agent:noop=true
```

But when I tried to run it massively I created this script you can find bellow but is not working. Could you guys help me please?

```
    $InputServerList=Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" .\ServerList.txt
    $pw = convertto-securestring 'PASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force
    $mycreds = new-object -typename 
    System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist 
    "domain\myuser",$pw

    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    $InputServerList | ForEach {
if ($session_id=new-pssession -computername $_.IPAddress -credential $mycreds)
{
    #If we reached here it is because credentials were OK on the first attempt so we now silently continue on errors
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}; $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; $webClient.DownloadFile('https://bod-T2.com:8140/packages/current/install.ps1', 'install.ps1'); .\install.ps1 extension_requests:pp_role=utility extension_requests:pp_environment=e1 agent:noop=true
    write-host "$($_.ServerName) was configured"  -BackgroundColor 00 -ForegroundColor 10
    Remove-PSSession $Session_id
} else {
    write-host "$($_.ServerName) $($_.IPaddress) Unable to connect"  -BackgroundColor RED -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
}
```

So basically I need to run this in multiple servers:

```
 [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}; $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; $webClient.DownloadFile('https://bod-T2.com:8140/packages/current/install.ps1', 'install.ps1'); .\install.ps1 extension_requests:pp_role=utility extension_requests:pp_environment=e1 agent:noop=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you don't seem to actually *use* your `$session_id`, have a look at [invoke-command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1)

You need to do something like:

```
$MySB = {
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
    $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $webClient.DownloadFile('https://bod-T2.com:8140/packages/current/install.ps1', 'install.ps1')
    .\install.ps1 extension_requests:pp_role=utility extension_requests:pp_environment=e1 agent:noop=true
}

invoke-command -Session $session_id -ScriptBlock $MySB
```

Comment: I tried the way you showme but not luck I'm getting the following error:

new-pssession : [COMPUTERNAME] Connecting to remote server SERVERNAME failed with the following error message : The WinRM
client cannot process the request. It cannot determine the content type of the HTTP response from the destination
computer. The content type is absent or invalid. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At C:\Users\username\agentP.ps1:8 char:18
+ ... $session_id=new-pssession -computername $_.IPAddress -credential $myc ...

Comment: Sounds like you have remoting disabled or something like that. Its erroring on your new-pssession line. Get your remoting set up, make sure you can build a session and then actually use the session via invoke-command. Your inital code built a session and never used it.